# What causes these signs to follow this relation?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

Can you find why does the below relation hold true?

[image]

Hint 1

> Salt + pepper = ?

Hint 2

> Recycle ________ ?

Comment: another hint maybe?

Comment: The shapes are important(but are required only in the  in the final step). Before that, you have **salt and pepper**  inside the boxes. Then...